# Ripple effect on a grid - any idea how they're doing this?

Tags: flash, 2d-games

I'm just wondering how the this app accomplishes this particular ripple effect:

http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/6182/music.swf

This is the Tone Matrix game you may have played. No implementation, just wondering about the algorithm here. I have some theories but I'd like to know yours! Sorry if this is a terrible question.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two approaches to a system like this. Both (of course) involve a timer or an enter_frame listener that will update the screen.

1) Update based on 'neighbors': Every new update, every node asks the neighbors if there is a 'wave' coming in (so store both direction and 'intensity' for the wave). After being activated the node uses some decay function to slowly become inactive again. A naive implementation of this solution will certainly not show a circle

2) Update based on original source: A square that sends out a note will be highlighted, based on the time since the trigger the value of the square will fade out. A circle will be drawn depending on the time since the trigger, and all squares that hit the circle will light up. This should keep the visual really shaped like a circle.